# Cross project issues in fogbugz?

Tags: fogbugz

Is there a way in Fogbugz to track cross project cases?
For example, we have a business logic dll that is used in both the winform client as the web client. There was a bug there that needed solving in this dll.
Is there a way to make it so that adding a case to the project of the dll would autoamatically add this to the depending projects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No there isn't a way to do this.  You could either create two cases (one in each project) and link them, or in the upcoming FogBugz 7, you could make a subcase.  But the only alternative to do this automatically would be to write something which scanned for these using the API and auto created the linked case.

Answer (score 0):

I think you may get more focussed answers at the [Fogbugz Support Forum](http://support.fogcreek.com/?fogbugz).

Comment: Maybe, but I like the SO forms so much..
I wish the whole internet was using the SO system. Actually, I wish the whole world was using the So system.
Ask Question => where are my keys?